# Validate Form Data With Combination of Client Values and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have spent quite a lot of time trying to figure this out myself but am new to using jquery and ajax and it is probably something simple...

I have a quote request form that I want to submit and I want to validate the details before submission. Some of this can be done in simple javascript and that part is working fine. I also need to get some values back from a mysql database and validate those which is where I am having problems.

On my HTML form, I have this line

```
<form id="quoteform" onsubmit=" return validateHire()" method="post" action="quote-results.php">
```

Which calls a validation script which is contained in a separate file which is included in the page containing the form.

The validateHire script is as follows:

```
    function validateHire(){

alert("Hire Validation Script Being Called!");

// set the colllection date and time
var collectionDate = new Date ($("#collectiondate").datepicker('getDate'));
var collectionHour = ($("#collectionTime").val()).substr(0,2);
collectionDate.setHours(collectionHour);
var collectionMinute = ($("#collectionTime").val()).substr(3,4);
collectionDate.setMinutes(collectionMinute);

// set the return date and time
var returnDate = new Date ($("#returndate").datepicker('getDate'));
var returnHour = ($("#returnTime").val()).substr(0,2);
returnDate.setHours(returnHour);
var returnMinute = ($("#returnTime").val()).substr(3,4);
returnDate.setMinutes(returnMinute);

// calculate the length of hire and add additional day if necessary
var timeDiff = returnHour - collectionHour
var totaldays = Math.floor(((returnDate - collectionDate)/1000)/60/60/24);

if(totaldays <1 && totaldays >-1){
totaldays=1;
}

// if(timeDiff > 2){
totaldays = totaldays + 1;
alert(totaldays)
}

// get the collection and return day to check if it is a weekend hire
var collectionDay = collectionDate.getDay();
var returnDay = returnDate.getDay();

// validate if the hire is a friday or saturday it meets minimum length
if(collectionDay == 5 && totaldays <3){
$("#errorbox").slideDown('fast');
$("#errormessage").html("Hires Starting on a Friday Must be a Minimum of 3 Days");
return false;
}

if(collectionDay == 6 && totaldays <2){
$("#errorbox").slideDown('fast');
$("#errormessage").html("Hires Starting on a Saturday Must be a Minimum of 2 Days");
return false;
}

checkServerSide();
function checkServerSide()
{
alert("now checking server side!");
$.post("sproc-test.php",{q: totaldays, cdt: collectionDate, cTime: collectionTime, cLoc: CollectionLocation, cDay: collectionDay, cDas: collectionDateAsString, rDate: returnDate, rTime: returnTime, rLoc: returnLocation, rDay: returnDay, rdas: returnDateAsString},
function(data){
var minHire = data.minhire;
alert(minHire); 

$('#testvalue').val(minHire);

          }, "json"); 
alert("This is the end of the check server side function");
}

if($('#testvalue').val() == 1){
$("#errorbox").slideDown('fast');
$("#errormessage").html("The Hire is not long enough to meet the requried minimum!");
return false;
}


}
```

The first part works fine and prompts the user with the correct error message and the form is not submitted however when it comes to the checkServerSide function I have problems.

The php script should return an array which I then try to access after the post and take a value and set it to a hidden form field so that I can validate against that however, according to Firebug, there is nothing actually being posted to the page that I am trying to submit the form too so wondering if my $post syntax is just wrong? also, the alert before the $post call works but the one after doesn't also leading me to wonder if I have messed something up here? although when looking in the firefox error console, there are not errors being reported.

I hope I have sufficiently explained what I am trying to achieve but I have not been clear enough then please let me know. Also, as I mentioned I am very new to this so I would really appreciate an easy to understand explanation of what I am doing wrong and if there is a better way to achieve this.

Huge thanks for any assistance! :)

Kind Regards

Mike

Comment: Sorry, missed the line containing the form validation call in the html <form id="quoteform" onsubmit=" return validateHire()" method="post" action="quote-results.php">